# How to find a specific row in a table for every record of another table

Tags: sql, sybase, sap-ase

This is what the table looks like -

---

```
time                    id     code

8/22/1999 12:00:00 AM   0001    A <------------ no
8/24/2001 6:03:02 AM    0001    A
6/27/2002 4:45:20 PM    0001    B  
5/8/2003 9:03:13 AM     0001    B  
5/8/2003 10:02:34 AM    0001    A <------------ no
6/9/2008 10:43:03 AM    0001    A
11/22/2011 3:42:10 PM   0001    A
4/11/2012 2:03:49 PM    0001    D  
4/11/2012 2:04:00 PM    0001    D  
12/6/2017 9:30:17 PM    0001    A <------------ yes
12/6/2017 9:30:17 PM    0001    A
12/6/2017 10:06:11 PM   0001    A
12/7/2017 3:24:58 AM    0001    C  
1/3/2018  5:02:13 PM    0001    C
```

0001 is an ID from another table. CODE can flip from A to B to C to D any time and in any order. I need to find the most recent occurrence when the code flipped to A from any other code. In this example it happens in the row indicated with "yes". The "no" records are not valid because there is a later occurrence of this situation.

Can't figure out how to go about this. This probably needs a stored procedure, going record by record, maintaining state and figuring out the value.

Edit:

I was wondering if I could somehow add a column called grp like this -

```
id code

A 1
A 1
B 2
B 2
A 3
A 3
A 3
D 4
D 4
A 5
A 5
A 5
C 6
C 6
```

Then I would be able to get-

```
max of the min(grp) group by grp
```

Comment: What database you uses? Mysql? SqlServer? Oracle?

Comment: Hey, I am using Sybase which I believe to be very similar to SQL server.

Comment: I am not familiar with SyBase, but I found SyBase support [ROWID ( table-name ) …FROM table-name](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc38151.1603/doc/html/san1278453138632.html), that means you can query out all codes with RowID from specific ID, then exec one sub query to find out the code whose sub.RowID=master.RowID-1

Comment: or using join like this: select * from 
(select *, ROWID(codes) RowNum from codes from id='0001') w1
left join (select *, ROWID(codes) RowNum from codes from id='0001') w2
on w1.RowNum=w2.RowNum+1
where w1.code<>w2.code

Comment: Sybase has 4x RDBMS products (ASE, SQLAnywhere, IQ, Advantage) so, which one are you using?

Comment: It is Sybase ASE. And your solution works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is Sybase ASE, though most of the following is fairly simple SQL which should convert easily into other RDBMS products

First we'll see if we can find the 3 rows where `code` changed to 'A'

```
select  f1.[time],
        f1.id,
        f1.code
from    fliptable f1
where   f1.code = 'A'
and     (   -- see if the previous record has a code!='A';  to find the 'previous' 
            -- record we find the row with max(time) < current record's time

                exists (select  1
                        from    fliptable f2
                        where   f2.id = f1.id
                        and     f2.code != f1.code
                        and     f2.[time] = (select     max(f3.[time])
                                                from    fliptable f3
                                                where   f3.id = f1.id
                                                and     f3.[time] < f1.[time]))
        or
            -- catch case where the 'first' row in the table has code='A'

            not exists (select  1
                        from    fliptable f4
                        where   f4.id = f1.id
                        and     f4.[time] < f1.[time])
        )

order by f1.[time]
go

 time                            id   code
 ------------------------------- ---- ----
             Aug 22 1999 12:00AM 0001 A
             May  8 2003 10:02AM 0001 A
             Dec  6 2017  9:30PM 0001 A
             Dec  6 2017  9:30PM 0001 A     <=== side effect of having a dup row in the data
```

From here we should be able to add a `top 1` and flip to `order by / desc` to pull the last/newest record ...

```
select  top 1
        f1.[time],
        f1.id,
        f1.code
from    fliptable f1
where   f1.code = 'A'
and     (       exists (select  1
                        from    fliptable f2
                        where   f2.id = f1.id
                        and     f2.code != f1.code
                        and     f2.[time] = (select     max(f3.[time])
                                                from    fliptable f3
                                                where   f3.id = f1.id
                                                and     f3.[time] < f1.[time]))
        or
            not exists (select  1
                        from    fliptable f4
                        where   f4.id = f1.id
                        and     f4.[time] < f1.[time])
        )

order by f1.[time] desc
go

 time                            id   code
 ------------------------------- ---- ----
             Dec  6 2017  9:30PM 0001 A
```

Tested on ASE 15.7 SP138